# How would I parse JSON with use of API in React-Native?

Tags: json, react-native, expo

I am trying to parse 4, 4c in departures, but it does not work.

Comment: Whats "4, 4c in departures"? What do you mean by "it does not work"? What do you want it to do? Also i see zero evidence of any attempted parsing in the code above.

Comment: return fetch('https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/6090282/live.json?app_id=d7180b02&app_key=47b460aac35e55efa666a99f713cff28&group=route&nextbuses=yes')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {

  alert( this.setState({data : responseJson.departures}));

Comment: I think this one is parsing...

Comment: if you click the Api key, you can see the deaprture :{ "4" :[...], "4c":[...] }

Comment: That fetch response is not parsing, its setting the data to State. Also there is no 4 or 4c in that API key. only 4A

Comment: let me know what parsing method is??

Comment: How would I get 4A, I tried to do this.setState({data : responseJson.departures.4A}), it seems 4A is not approved in the code...

Comment: Can you console.log the responseJson and see what is coming back from the fetch?

Comment: i got sth like Object {"4A": Array [.....] } looks like it is inside of departures object . How would I retrieve 4A array??

Comment: console.log "responseJson.departures.4A". Does that give you anything back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` doest not return a result that why you got undefined.

try this one

```
this.setState({data : responseJson.departures});
alert( JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
```

Comment: <Text>{this.state.data}</Text> is what you want i think.

Comment: @DHC <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)}</Text>